# Syntax Error, unexpected $end

Tags: php

Been trying for hours this php embedding in html but something is wrong as i get a error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\profile.php on line 678

```
<select value='$pays' name='pays' id='pays' style='width: 204px;margin-bottom: 5px; outline-width:0;'>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pays_az, pays_zz, pays_or FROM in_lays WHERE pays_flush = '1' ORDER BY pays_nom ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result) )
{  ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['dd']; ?>"

     <?php   if($row['dd_id'] == $pays)
     {
        echo 'selected="selected" ' ;
     }
     else
     {
           if($row['dd_id'] == "61")
        {
       echo 'selected="selected"' ;
        }
     }
 ?>><?php echo $row['lala']; ?></option>
<?php}?>

</select>
```

dont pay attention to the names in the sql request.

Comment: is it the code of whole page? If not plz provide whole code.

Comment: @Himadri pasting 678+ lines of code seems excessive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Маке

```
<?php}?>
```

to

```
<?php } ?>
```

And if in first row $pays a php variable. If yes - please echo it

Comment: yes! thank you GOsha it was the <?php}?>

Answer (score 4):

change `<?php}?>` to `<?php } ?>`, i think thats the problem (and you should realy try to format your code better, it's a horror to read that.)

**EDIT:**
without changing too much, i would format your code like this:

```
<select value="<? echo $pays; ?>" name="pays" id="pays" style="width: 204px;margin-bottom: 5px; outline-width:0;">
    <?
    $result = mysql_query("
            SELECT
                pays_az,
                pays_zz,
                pays_or
            FROM
                in_lays
            WHERE
                pays_flush = '1'
            ORDER BY
                pays_nom ASC
            ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
        <option value="<? echo $row['dd']; ?>"
            <?
            if($row['dd_id'] == $pays || $row['dd_id'] == "61"){
                echo ' selected="selected"';
            }
            ?>
        ><? echo $row['lala']; ?></option>
    <?
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Note: i used (evil) short php-tags, but you can change that. i write the opening `{` in the same linne as the `if` or `while`-statement and don't use too much spaces (but that depends on personal preference). the important thing is to indent your code to be readable.

Comment: Can you explain why <?php}?> doesn't work?

Comment: how would you format it?

@Himadri , it's just the parser that needs space to recognize the php tag, there it must take all as one entity

Comment: @Himadri: as tada mentioned, the compiler needs a space after the opening-tag - @tada: see my edit

Comment: yep, that's a horror. But is there really a way to format PHP inside HTML so that it's not?

Answer (score 3):

The error message “unexpected $end” means that one or more blocks are not properly closed like when a closing `}` is missing. But your code seems to be correct. You should take a look at your other control structures and see if everything is at its place.

---

**Edit**    I think I got it: Though your code seems to be syntactically correct, the `<?php}?>` is what the parser chokes on. Make it a `<?php }?>` and it should work.

Comment: @Oded No, it is not missing...

Comment: missed it somehow... disregard me...

Answer (score 1):

you did not close the while properly try :

```
<select value='$pays' name='pays' id='pays' style='width: 204px;margin-bottom: 5px; outline-width:0;'>  
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pays_az, pays_zz, pays_or FROM in_lays WHERE pays_flush = '1' ORDER BY pays_nom ASC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result) ):  ?>

<option value="<?php echo $row['dd']; ?>"

<?php   if($row['dd_id'] == $pays)
{
    echo 'selected="selected" ' ;
}
else
{
    if($row['dd_id'] == "61")
    {
        echo 'selected="selected"' ;
    }
}
?>

<?php echo $row['lala']; ?></option>  

<?php endwhile; ?>

</select>
```

Comment: oh.. good... I was not knowing about this alternate syntax..

Comment: No problem....
I think it's always better to use  
`while(....) endwhile; `